# Alternative way to prevent use of multiple loop / PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Im trying to select the difference between 2(Two) Array. And yes, I have a solution using loop. But I think its a big problem because using so many loops make the process slow. Im asking if there's alternative way or a simple way on how to do it with the same output.

This is my code

```
$unique = [];
$first_array =  [["SERIAL_NUMBER" => "1"]];
$second_array = [["SERIAL_NUMBER" => "1"],["SERIAL_NUMBER" => "2"]];


foreach ($second_array as $second) {
    foreach($first_array as $first)
    {
        if($second['SERIAL_NUMBER'] == $first['SERIAL_NUMBER'])
        {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $unique[] = $second;
}

foreach ($first_array as $first) {
    foreach($second_array as $second)
    {
        if($first['SERIAL_NUMBER'] == $second['SERIAL_NUMBER'])
        {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $unique[] = $first;
}
echo json_encode($unique);
```

The result will be the difference of 2(two) array.

PS: This is base on specific key of the multidimensional array (SERIAL_NUMBER)

```
[{"SERIAL_NUMBER":"2"}]
```

Comment: Maybe the array_diff() function will help you? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: array_diff not working on multidimensional arrray :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that most things will use some sort of loop, even if you don't see the loop in your code it may be done internally.

This code uses `array_udiff()`, mainly to simplify the code, but also as it's a multidimensional array - you can't just use `array_diff()`.  The function just compare the SERIAL_NUMBER values of each elements.

This is done once in each direction (1 => 2 and 2 => 1) and then merges the results...

```
function udiffCompare($a, $b)
{
    return $a['SERIAL_NUMBER'] <=> $b['SERIAL_NUMBER'];
}

$arrdiff1 = array_udiff($first_array, $second_array, 'udiffCompare');
$arrdiff2 = array_udiff($second_array, $first_array, 'udiffCompare');
$difference = array_merge($arrdiff1, $arrdiff2);
```

Comment: So this also uses loop internally? in terms of speed, is this also the same as my solution before?

Comment: or its more faster than forloops that seen on my code?

Comment: The result will be the same. But PHP functions like this are written in(C or C++ im not sure) and are most times much faster then write your own loops

Comment: Ah okay okay! Now I know, thanks mate. Will accept this answer, besides it shortened the line of codes. ^_^